# Floating DIV and P element

Tags: css, css-float

While using float attribute two div elements go adjacent to each other, but two paragraph elements do not; rather the 'p' element throw up a weird result.

Also, it is strange that when I float two 'div' elements and two 'p' elements, the result is better aligned.

My 3 code examples may be able to explain (please note: the link to my 3rd code is in my comment below.  I do not have enough reputation points to put 3 links):

Code 1:https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshsukhani/v7r45zeg/

```css
#superhero {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

#supervillain {
  background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<p id="superhero">
  SUPERHERO
</p>
<p id="supervillain">
  SUPERVILLAIN
</p>
```

Code 2:https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshsukhani/51mtncx8/

```css
#hero {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  float: left;
}

#villain {
  background-color: lightcyan;
}
```

```html
<div id="hero">
  HERO
</div>
<div id="villain">
  VILLAIN
</div>
```

Code 3 :

```css
#hero {
  background-color: lightcoral;
  float: left;
 }

 #villain {
  background-color: lightcyan;
 }
  
  #superhero {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
 }

 #supervillain {
  background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<div id="hero">
 HERO
</div>
<div id="villain">
 VILLAIN
</div>
<p id="superhero">
 SUPERHERO
</p>
<p id="supervillain">
 SUPERVILLAIN
</p>
```

Why such different results for div only, p only and 'div and p in a single code'?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dipeshsukhani/86j15kku/3/

Comment: So... the question is?

Comment: Why such different results for div only, p only and 'div and p in a single code'?

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples work similarly in terms of floating. What confuses you and makes you think that `p` version doesn't work is that `p` has default margin top/bottom (`-webkit-margin-before: 1em;` in Webkit for top) styles applied by browser. Those margins make first (floated) paragraph look like it's not floated, although it is.

It's easy to test by resetting margin to `0`:

```css
#superhero {
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

#supervillain {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<p id="superhero">
  SUPERHERO
</p>
<p id="supervillain">
  SUPERVILLAIN
</p>
```